# All languages are regular, as unions of singleton languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata

We know that singleton languages (languages containing exactly one word) are regular. We also know that a finite union of regular languages is also regular.

Suppose there is a non-regular language $L$. For every finite subset $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_i\}$ of elements of $L$, we can take the corresponding singleton languages and compute their union. This new language (which is a subset of $L$) should be regular. Now we do the same with rest of the language.

Finally, we must have $sL_1, sL_2,\dots, sL_n,\dots$ which are all subsets of $L$ that are finite regular languages. If we take the union of $sL_1, sL_2,\dots, sL_i$, where $i$ is finite, we again have a regular language. We do this for all languages obtained from $L$.

If we keep doing such "finite" unions of regular languages, we will eventually obtain $L$, which must be regular because we obtained it from a finite union of regular languages.

This obviously isn't right, but I don't understand why.

Comment: You have shown that any *finite* set of words is regular: true. No infinite set of words is reached by your process, leaving its regularity moot.

Comment: Try to apply your procedure to the language which contains all elements and tell us after how many steps your procedure stops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same "argument" would show that $\mathbb{N}$ is finite since it's the union of finite sets $$\mathbb{N}=\{0\}\cup\{0,1\}\cup\{0,1,2\}\cup ...$$ The point is that knowing that a given property is preserved under a given operation does not mean that it's preserved under "infinite iterations" of that operation.

Answer (score 2):

You proved that any *finite* languages are regular. All the languages that you generated are finite.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *keep doing* it an infinite number of times before you reach any infinite languages. So your proof will involve [transfinite induction. As Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction):

> Transfinite induction is an extension of mathematical induction to
>   well-ordered sets, for example to sets of ordinal numbers or cardinal
>   numbers.
>
> Let P(α) be a property defined for all ordinals α. Suppose that
>   whenever P(β) is true for all β < α, then P(α) is also true. Then
>   transfinite induction tells us that P is true for all ordinals.
>
> Usually the proof is broken down into three cases:
>
> - *Zero case*: Prove that P(0) is true.
> - *Successor case*: Prove that for any successor ordinal α+1, P(α+1) follows from P(α) (and, if necessary, P(β) for all β < α).
> - *Limit case*: Prove that for any limit ordinal λ, P(λ) follows from [P(β) for all β < λ].

It is the *limit case* you won't be able to prove.